# How to Send mail through code without opening MailComposer or new view in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

```
-(IBAction)addbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
          mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailCont setSubject:@"yo!"];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:@[@"address@example.com"]];
       [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Don't ever want to give you up" isHTML:YES];

        [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    //handle any error
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have a code like this which work. But I do not want to open MFMailComposer. I just want to send mail directly on the click of button.This code open MFMailComposer.I don't want to open it.Please Help.

Comment: Apple does not provide this in there SDK, since you could send spam from the user e-mail address. However you could always send e-mail directly thru an SMTP server in code, but since asking for libraries to this is offtopic for stackoverflow you will need to google this yourself.

Comment: @Mujtaba check my answer below it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Check link below :--

[SKPSMTPMessage](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage)

This one is for sending mails in background with out any user interaction...

Use Code Below to use this library...

```
SKPSMTPMessage *emailMessage = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc]init];
emailMessage.fromEmail = @"SENDER MAIL ID";
emailMessage.toEmail = @"RECEIPENT MAIL ID";
emailMessage.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
emailMessage.requiresAuth = YES;
```

**YOUR LOGIN CREDENTIALS OF YOUR EMAIL TO SEND EMAIL**

```
emailMessage.login = @"YOUR EMAIL ID";
emailMessage.pass = @"PASSWORD OF YOUR MAIL ACCOUNT";
emailMessage.subject = @"YOUR SUBJECT TO SEND MAIL";
emailMessage.wantsSecure = YES;
emailMessage.delegate = self;

NSString *password = @"PASSWORD";

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your password is : %@", password];

NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey, message, kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, @"8bit" , kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];

[emailMessage setParts:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart, nil]];
[emailMessage send];
```

Hope this help you...

**you have to give login email and password of your/company email from which you want to send mail ...**

```
emailMessage.login = @"YOUR EMAIL ID";
emailMessage.pass = @"PASSWORD OF YOUR MAIL ACCOUNT";
```

Comment: I don't have labery for SKPSMTPMessage . Can you provide

Comment: @Mujtaba have you checked link i have provided?

Comment: I am not understanding that example

Comment: I just want to send the email from app.The mail id will be taken from textbox and on the click of send it will directly send.

Comment: check my updated answer.
you have to give login credentials of your email from which you want to send mail...
also you have to change `relayHost` with your host like :- smtp.yahoo.com ...